# GraphQL request with JS

Tags: javascript, graphql

It's my first time playing with GraphQL and I'm kinda new to API in general. 
So I'm having a hard time just doing a test request to GraphQL of how it works from a starting exemple on their docs.

- First I installed GrapgQL with `npm install graphql --save` (not sure if I needed to do that,  it might be only for server, it was not clear to me)
- Then, this is my code to request :

> ```
> const response = await fetch(`/graphql`, {
>     method: "POST",
>     headers: {
>         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
>         'Accept': 'application/json',
>     },
>     body: JSON.stringify({query: '{ hello }' })
> })
> console.log(response.json());
> ```

This is returning me a response that is undefined.

I am wondering what I'm missing or doing wrong?
Thank you for the answers

**Edit :** 
I first thought that their documentation was referring to an existing endpoint that was made for test, but I was not sure anymore so I tested on the Github V4 API and I get an empty response instead while on their explorer I have results. Here is my new Code.

> ```
> const response = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/graphql`, {
>     method: "POST",
>     headers: {
>         Authorization: `Token ${token}`,
>         Accept: 'application/vnd.github.starfox-preview+json',
>     },
>     body: JSON.stringify({query:
>             '{' +
>             '  repository(name: "myrepo", owner: "myowner") {' +
>             '    issues(last: 100) {' +
>             '      nodes {' +
>             '        number' +
>             '        title' +
>             '        timelineItems(itemTypes: MOVED_COLUMNS_IN_PROJECT_EVENT, last: 10) {' +
>             '          nodes {' +
>             '            ... on AddedToProjectEvent {' +
>             '              createdAt' +
>             '            }' +
>             '            ... on MovedColumnsInProjectEvent {' +
>             '              createdAt' +
>             '            }' +
>             '          }' +
>             '        }' +
>             '      }' +
>             '    }' +
>             '  }' +
>             '}'
>     })
> })
> console.log(response.json());
> ```
>
> My console.log returns `Promise { <pending> }` 
>   and I get this error `body used already for: https://api.github.com/graphql`

Am I not defining or using the body the right way?

Comment: This is a browser environment right? `.json()` returns a promise. You can fulfill a promise using `.then()` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Comment: @JonathanRosa No its actually not, its a node.js Rest API and I'm calling a GraphQL API from it. Your comment must mean that I am way off-track...

Comment: Nah, I just assumed browser because `fetch()` is native there but not at node. Try looking over the documentation of your fetch implementation.

Comment: did you start graphql server?

Comment: @Xesenix I first though that graphql had their server for a test endpoint, your comment made me realised I was probably wrong so I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

The line `'Content-Type': 'application/json',` was missing in the header, wich make the HTTP POST body contents treated  as the GraphQL query string.

So my code ended up being like this :

```
const response = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/graphql`, {
method: "POST",
headers: {
    Authorization: `Token ${token}`,
    Accept: 'application/vnd.github.starfox-preview+json',
   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
},
body: JSON.stringify({query:
        '{' +
        '  repository(name: "myrepo", owner: "myowner") {' +
        '    issues(last: 100) {' +
        '      nodes {' +
        '        number' +
        '        title' +
        '        timelineItems(itemTypes: MOVED_COLUMNS_IN_PROJECT_EVENT, last: 10) {' +
        '          nodes {' +
        '            ... on AddedToProjectEvent {' +
        '              createdAt' +
        '            }' +
        '            ... on MovedColumnsInProjectEvent {' +
        '              createdAt' +
        '            }' +
        '          }' +
        '        }' +
        '      }' +
        '    }' +
        '  }' +
        '}'
})
```

})
console.log(response.json());